# Why is codelens spamming my code in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, codelens

I see how codelens can be cool but so far it's only been very disrupting. It makes my actual code very hard to read.
Is it possible to somehow group the codelens appearances or reset them becuse I'm pretty sure this is a bug:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, you can change it at Options -> Text Editor -> CodeLens

[image: CodeLens settings in Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: I know it is "expected" but I am pretty sure it is not supposed to show codelens after every single line of code

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic It doesn't. It just so happens that every single line of *your* code is one for which it shows.

Comment: And why does it show that exactly? (Since each line has 0 reviews, 0 authors, 0 changes)